# LibGDX Sprite not moving

Tags: libgdx, sprite

I'm making a game in LibGDX, and up until now, have just been using shapes and debug lines to outline the player and enemies. But when I wanted to add a graphic for my player, I downloaded a png of a spacehsip and packed it in TexturePacker. In my PlayScreen(my main game screen), I constructed the sprite like this:

```
TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("Spaceship.atlas"));
sprite = new Sprite(new TextureRegion(atlas.findRegion("spaceship")));
sprite.rotate(-90);
sprite.setScale(0.1f);
```

Then in my render method, I call a method I named renderSprites(), which looks like this:

```
public void renderSprites()
{
    game.batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(game.batch);
    sprite.setPosition(player.getX(), player.getY());
    game.batch.end();
}
```

My player is an Actor that represents the Body I want the Sprite to cover. But when I run my game, the spaceship Sprite is rendered but never moves. It always remains stationary, and I don't know why. Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the player is moving (is player.getX() and player.getY() changing)? What if you call setPosition before draw?

Comment: Use TextureRegion instead of Sprite. It doesn't make sense to use Sprite when your already have a player class.  And it doesn't make sense that you are drawing it before moving it in your code above.